# Casting a game on mobile phone background

Tags: android, iphone, unity-game-engine

As my concept, there only exists a simple icon-size game object on the screen, so the users can interact with the game and do their stuff with their own phone at the same time, just like the bubble icon in messenger.

Yet the greatest problem is how could I combine the application and the home screen?

Concept like:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.westplain.antlife

[image]

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I tried on searching the methodology they probably used on the example but nothing outcomes. Not understanding what classes, libraries they used to combine the application and the home screen, how should I get start with it? Appreciate if you could understand I can't even move my first step on it.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good entry point to start looking for the right things:
https://codingshark.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/how-to-draw-on-top-of-other-applications/

Comment: ...but it doesn't apply to Unity (to be fair, there *isn't* a Unity solution here).

Comment: sure, but you probably could write a plugin for Unity (? - mostly guessing here), shouldn't be that much of a problem...and on a plus side, if it doesn't exist yet, you could put it on store.

Comment: The link brings a huge step for me, but that's kinda true to @Draco18s. We cannot directly apply what the link does to Unity. Somehow need to separate it into 2 apps (1 app and 1 game).

Comment: @Jax297 I don't think so. As I understand it, the Unity application is wrapped in a container app (publishing to anything other than WebGL or Desktop is a transcompile to another project type: Android, XCode, etc) and it's the Unity half that doesn't support transparency. Hololens gets around that only due to *how* it renders: the device *literally can't* draw black.

Comment: @SimonLeung See above comment to Jax (can't ping two people).